# Report only showing First report item

Tags: vb.net, reporting-services

within a vb.net report, I have added a list item to add data from each item of the dataset (list of t) in terms of textbox.Values how can I edit the expression below so each item from the datalist is shown rather than the first value in all blocks?

```
=First(Fields!race.Value, "DataSet1")
```

Answer (score 0):

never mind worked it out..... now things are in a list I can add data values to each of the text boxes individually.